# Wrong except in asyncio.Queue.put?

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio

asyncio\queues.py

```
@coroutine
def put(self, item):
    """Put an item into the queue.

    Put an item into the queue. If the queue is full, wait until a free
    slot is available before adding item.

    This method is a coroutine.
    """
    while self.full():
        putter = futures.Future(loop=self._loop)
        self._putters.append(putter)
        try:
            yield from putter
        except:
            putter.cancel()  # Just in case putter is not done yet.
            if not self.full() and not putter.cancelled():
                # We were woken up by get_nowait(), but can't take
                # the call.  Wake up the next in line.
                self._wakeup_next(self._putters)
            raise
    return self.put_nowait(item)
```

In my view, `putter` can be done by `cancel`, `set_exception` or `set_result`. `get_nowait` use `set_result`. only `cancel` and `set_exception` will throw exception, then `except:` can occur. I think `except:` is not needed.

Why does it add a `except:` to `Wake up the next in line`?

**Update:**@Vincent
`_wakeup_next` call `set_result`. `set_result` will execute `self._state = _FINISHED`. `task1.cancel()` will `self._fut_waiter.cancel()` which return False. So, task1 will be **not cancelled**.

@Vincent thanks very much

the key cause is task.cancel can cancel task though the future which task is waiting has been set_result(self._state = _FINISHED).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the task waiting for `putter` is cancelled, `yield from putter` raises a `CancelledError`. That can happen after `get_nowait()` is called, and you want to make sure the other putters are notified that a new slot is available in the queue.

Here's an example:

```
async def main():
    # Create a full queue
    queue = asyncio.Queue(1)
    await queue.put('A')
    # Schedule two putters as tasks
    task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(queue.put('B'))
    task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(queue.put('C'))
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    # Make room in the queue, print 'A'
    print(queue.get_nowait())
    # Cancel task 1 before giving the control back to the event loop
    task1.cancel()
    # Thankfully, the putter in task 2 has been notified
    await task2
    # Print 'C'
    print(await queue.get())
```

---

EDIT: More information about what happens internally:

- `queue.get_nowait()`: `putter.set_result(None)` is called; the putter state is now `FINISHED`, and `task1` will wake up when the control is given back to the event loop.
- `task1.cancel()`: `task1._fut_waiter` is already finished, so `task1._must_cancel` is set to `True` in order to raise a `CancelledError` the next time `task1` runs.
- `await task2`:

  - The control is given back to the control loop, and `task1._step()` runs. A `CancelledError` is thrown inside the coroutine: `task1._coro.throw(CancelledError())`.
  - `queue.put` catches the exception. Since the queue is not full and `'B'` is not going to be inserted, the next putter in the queue has to be notified: `self._wakeup_next(self._putters)`.
  - Then the `CancelledError` is re-raised and caught in `task1._step()`. `task1` now actually cancels itself (`super().cancel()`).

Comment: _wakeup_next call set_result. set_result will execute 'self._state = _FINISHED'.  task1.cancel() will 'self._fut_waiter.cancel()' which return False.

Comment: @Vince  `task1` and `putter` are not the same future. The putter (`task1._fut_waiter`) is indeed finished, but `task1` is not, until it gets canceled and `task1._must_cancel` is set to `True`.

Comment: In this case, task1 is pending(not started) when task1.cancel, so it just is cancelled before being started. get_nowait doesn't wake up any putter(except in task1 is not trigged). Maybe we need to create a sample to cancel a running task1.

Comment: @Vince See if my edit helps. You can also run my example with `self._wakeup_next(self._putters)` commented out. You should notice that the program hangs because `queue.put('C')` hasn't been notified.

Comment: it doesn't hang after commentting

Comment: @Vince My mistake, it is fixed now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111008/discussion-between-vince-and-vincent).